# How to append a value to a dict inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to append to a list of dictionaries without adding another dictionary. I want to append to `response[0]`.

I tried `.append` and `.extend` but it's what I'm looking for. `.append` creates a new dictionary whereas `.extend` does not add to the dictionary.

```
response =[]
response.append({
  'id': "a",
  'name': "standard"})

response[0].extend({}
  'types': "b"})

print (response)
```

I've tried `response.extend` and `.append` but the result is not what I want

I expect to see `[{'id': 'a', 'name': 'standard', 'types': 'b'}]` but I get errors if I try to append/extend response.

Comment: `response[0]['types'] = 'b'` should do what you want.

Comment: I think what you're describing is neither extending nor appending to the list but adding a key-value pair to the dictionary inside it, in which case `response[0]["types"] = "b"`. But it's not very clear.

Comment: Are you sure this is all you want? if yes below answers will work, if not please make sure you elaborate your question with more code examples.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I still have to wrap my head around the concept a bit. Thee whole arrays kind of confused me.

What an amazing community.

Comment: Update: Follow up, what if the data structure is as such:
{"data":[{'id': 'a', 'name': 'standard', 'types': 'b'}, {'id': 'b', 'name': 'standard', 'types': 'c'}], "success":true:} and I'd like to add to the dictionary with id = a?

Comment: You should ask a separate question for that. See [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: But first see https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F; basic list and dictionary manipulation is covered in any Python tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the dict exists, then just treat it as a dict...

```
response[0]['types'] = 'b'
```

Comment: Update: Follow up, what if the data structure is as such:
{"data":[{'id': 'a', 'name': 'standard', 'types': 'b'}, {'id': 'b', 'name': 'standard', 'types': 'c'}], "success":true:} and I'd like to add to the dictionary with id = a?

Comment: Since you're using a list, you could have to for loop on your data to find the id 'a'

That would look like 


```
dataSet = {
    'data': [
        {'id': 'a', 'name': 'standard', 'types': 'b'}
        {'id': 'b', 'name': 'standard', 'types': 'c'}
    ]     
}

for elem in dataSet.get('data')
    if dataSet.get('data')[elem].get('id') == 'a':
        dataSet[data][elem][id]['some_new_field'] = 'some_value_i_set'
        break
```

Comment: a better layout would have been

```
dataSet = {
    'a': {'name': 'standard', 'types': 'b'}
    'b': {'name': 'standard', 'types': 'c'}
}
```

then you could just do 

```
dataSet['a']['any_old_field'] = 'some_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response[0].update({'id': "a", 'name': "standard"})
```

will update the `response[0]` dictionary.